# Make multiple select statements into one using SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query one table in my SQL Server DB using the following logic:

```
declare @crntusrdept nvarchar(128)
set @crntusrdept = 'A'

if @crntusrdept includes ('A', 'B', 'C') then (select * from comps where dept in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
if @crntusrdept includes ('D','E') then (select * from comps where dept in ('D','E'))
if @crntusrdept includes ('F', 'G') then (select * from comps where dept in ('F', 'G'))
if @crntusrdept includes ('H') then (select * from comps where dept in ('H'))
```

Comment: Does _"includes"_ mean that `@crntusrdept` can hold for eg `'Alpha'`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56743281/edit) your question to provide a sample data and the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select * 
from comps 
where @crntusrdept in ('A', 'B', 'C') and dept in ('A', 'B', 'C')
   or @crntusrdept in ('D', 'E') and dept in ('D', 'E')
   or @crntusrdept in ('F', 'G') and dept in ('F', 'G')
   or @crntusrdept in ('H') and dept in ('H')
```